# How to detect events like Sleep/Wake in linux

Tags: c++, events

I am wondering if there is any way to detect system wide events under linux such as:

- sleep
- wakeup

I need this for a project where i programmatically react to such events, but i am uncertain how and where to start. Maybe there is an api that i dont know yet.

Any hints? I would appreciate any help!

Edit:
The file "/var/log/syslog" contains the update for sleep and wakeup event, but this is not suitable for my usecase because it requires root permission to access this file.

Comment: I have generally used SIGTERM events when an application needs to handle these events 

Comment: This was crossposted twice to Unix and Linux (both deleted) and to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77514111/how-to-detect-events-like-sleep-wake-in-linux).  **Please only choose one site to post your questions to.**